I need to get custom field label from elemtor form after form submit
I created a plugin that adds an action to the "After submit actions" on Elementor form
I managed to get the fields with id and value, But what I need is the field label
// Getting submitted data
$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );

// Normalize form data.
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}

In this code field doesn't have label so It's not working.
I tried to get the label with this way, But it didn't work
$fields = [];
$labels = []; // To store labels for each field

foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
$labels[ $id ] = $field['label']; // Get the field label
}


Hi, can you share a example of $raw_fields and $fields arrays?
